# Show array value from database laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a data in database like this

```
id |    name    |   pic   |     level     |  team
1     John          3           user           
2     Lorem         4           user           
3     Ipsum         5          supervisor     
4     Dolor         5           admin
5     Amet                     manager        3,4
```

User id 5, as a manager can view people in their team, team id 3 and team id 4. I have tried to make that as an array

```
$id='5';
    $query = DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->first();

    $list[]=explode(',', $query->team);
```

and the result is

```
 array:1 [▼
   0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "3"
    1 => "4"
   ]
 ]
```

the problem is when I tried to get the data from id no 3 and number 4,

```
$result = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id',$list)->get();
    foreach($result as $res)
    {
        $d[]=$res->id;
    }
```

it's only show id number 3, id no 4 not shown

```
array:1 [▼
 0 => 3
]
```

Do you know where is the missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, it's because I insert an array to array.

```
$list=explode(',', $query->team);
```